# Trying to redirect to page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

No expert when it comes to JS/Jquery, but im trying to use this code, and once the registration sign up is done correctly, and the information is stored, instead of a alert box, i wanna have it redirect to another web page... This is what ive got so far, ive tried a few things, but none seem to be working... What am i doing wrong, and how to fix this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").click(function () {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();
        if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
            alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
        } else if ((password.length) < 8) {
            alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
        } else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
            alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
        } else {
            $.post("register.php", {
                name1: name,
                email1: email,
                password1: password
            }, function (data) {
                if (data == 'You have Successfully Registered.....') {
                      $("form")[0].reset();
                    }
               alert(data);
             });
         }
     });
});
```

Comment: Could you explain what is this line supposed to do? if (data == window.location = 'index.html';)

Comment: Check your console for errors, I believe this will cause a syntax error `if (data == window.location = 'index.html';)`

Comment: Nothing, meant to edit that out, it was may failed attempts at getting it redirect... The code that should there is as follows: `if (data == 'You have Successfully Registered.....') {
    $("form")[0].reset();
    }
    alert(data);
    });
    }
    });
    });`  ... And it just creates a alert box once the information is inputted correctly... Instead of that im trying to make it so it just redirects to a different page(basically a conformation page).

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data == "index.html"){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stripped version.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#register").click(function () {

        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();

        $.post("register.php", {
            name1: name,
            email1: email,
            password1: password
        }, function (data) {
            // check if registration ok
            location.href = 'index.html';
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Noob question, but where would that go? replace alert(data); with that? ... But wouldn't that null something?

Comment: Not sure if you're a PHP guy, but what should i change in the PHP file? ... This is all new ground for me, as im a C and Python Developer, so JS and PHP im still trying to learn. Here is the PHP file: http://pastebin.com/MXXebb8C